# Foundation SASS

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm trying out the new Foundation 6 framework, using SASS, but I'm struggling to understand the grid system. Based on the documentation and other example I've seen what I've done should be a simple 2,1 grid:

```
    @import 'foundation';

/* CUSTOM STYLES */

.container {
    @include grid-row(3);
    main {
        background: $primary-color;
        @include grid-column(2);
    }
    aside {
        background: $primary-color;
        @include grid-column(1);
    }
}
```

For some reason it results in this:

Grid problem

[image: Grid problem]

Comment: Can you post the html source as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this two ways. The first is by including `foundation-global-styles` in your main `app.scss` file. Here's an example `app.scss` file:

```
@charset 'utf-8';

@import 'settings';
@import 'foundation';

@include foundation-global-styles;
```

If you don't want to include all of Foundation's global styles, the specific CSS rule that fixes this issue is:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This rule makes all elements include padding and border sizes in width and height calculations. You'll probably run into less obstacles down the road if you include Foundation's [Global Styles](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/global.html) since they are mostly a bunch of resets for improving consistency across browsers.

---

**Note:** I deleted my other answer as this answer pinpoints the CSS that is the root of the problem.

Comment: Brill! Thanks so much! Wish they had made this clearer in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

use
require 'zurb-foundation' in ruby.config

refer http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sass-functions.html
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sass-mixins.html